# How to get rid of NVIDIA PowerMizer?

Tags: nvidia

I've been trying to turn off nvidia PowerMizer (that is set the performance level to 2 - max). I can do it with nvidia-settings, but it goes back to default after restart. Here's what I have tried:

- nvidia-settings as root - saving settings to `xorg.conf` and `~/.nvidia-settings-rc`
- adding `options nvidia NVreg_RegistryDwords="PerfLevelSrc=0x2222"` to `/etc/modprobe.d/nvidia.conf` - nothing happened
- adding Option `"RegistryDwords"` `"PowerMizerLevel=0x2"` `"PowerMizerLevelAC=0x2"` to `xorg.conf` under device section : gdm did not start up - had to delete `xorg.conf` to recover
- adding Option `"RegistryDwords"` `"PowerMizerEnable=0x0"` to `xorg.conf`: nothing happened

Any idea how I can do this?

---

**P.S.** Ubuntu 12.10

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to remove whatever you've added to xorg.conf, and add something like the following:

```
Section "Device"
  Identifier "NVIDIA GeForce"
  Driver     "nvidia"
  Option     "RegistryDwords" "PerfLevelSrc=0x3322; PowerMizerDefaultAC=0x1"
EndSection
```

`PerfLevelSrc=0x3322` means it's going to use fixed PowerMizer mode when on AC.

`PowerMizerDefaultAC=0x1` defines the power mode, with `0x1` being Maximum performance.

There is no need to reboot, just logout/login.

Comment: Still goes back to "adaptive"

Comment: Make sure the PowerMizer is enabled in the Nvidia Settings. If that still doesn't work, you might want to try `PerfLevelSrc=0x2222` instead of `PerfLevelSrc=0x3322`.

Comment: Makes no difference. I enabled PowerMizer in nvidia settings and added the line to xorg.conf (tried both). Still once I log back in it is back to 'adaptive' in nvidia settings

Comment: You are right, I forgot the `"RegistryDwords"` part. The above code has been corrected and tested, and should work. Let me know if it doesn't.

Comment: It worked! Thanks!
The drop-down menu in nvidia settings is still on adaptive, but the performance level stays on 2 and doesn't change which means the code is working

Answer (score 0):

There is an [unofficial patch](http://tendonto.tumblr.com/post/83809787100/patching-nvidia-settings-version-337-12) for recent versions of the proprietary NVIDIA graphics driver (334.21 and 337.12) that writes GPU target attributes like GPUPowerMizerMode to the configuration file of nvidia-settings. That means you can use the NVIDIA X Server Settings GUI to **permanently** set your desired performance level just as it should be.

Comment: the nvidia settings GUI is useless since graphics resolution is set so low cannot see/reach that part of the GUI window