# Set max power level of Nvidia PowerMizer to 1

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, overheating

I have Dell XPS with GTX 1050 and Ubuntu 18.04.

I am trying to set max performance level on my GPU so that my laptop does not heat up so much. The problem is that normally with the adaptive mode set in PowerMizer the power level is being set to max (3) when GPU utilization is around 4% and around 70 degrees. I would like to lock it to performance level 1.

I tried this solution:
[How to get rid of NVIDIA PowerMizer? | Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/232588/512556)
But after the restart, my pc hangs in black terminal forever. I have to use `ctrl+alt+f2` to remove those settings from xorg config and reboot again.

Answer (score 5):

Two comments,

One way to get what you ask is to create a file named /etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-user-registry.conf with the following single line ...

```
options nvidia NVreg_RegistryDwords="OverrideMaxPerf=0x2"
```

... then update your init ram disk and reboot

```
$ sudo update-initramfs -u
$ sudo shutdown -r now
```

Alternatively, use the following line for nvidia-user-registry.conf and the machine SHOULD use power level 0 when unplugged, and power level 1 when plugged in.

```
options nvidia NVreg_RegistryDwords="PowerMizerEnable=0x1;PerfLevelSrc=0x3322;PowerMizerDefault=0x3;PowerMizerDefaultAC=0x2"
```

Best of luck!